# How to create a menu and submenus in Python curses?

Tags: python, python-2.7, curses

AFAIK, there is no curses menu extension available in Python yet so you have to roll your own solution. I know about this patch http://bugs.python.org/issue1723038 but I don't what's the current state of it. I found a nice class for Python that wraps what I want called 'cmenu' here http://www.promisc.org/blog/?p=33 but I have a problem with that too. I want to make a menu where user can choose a highlighted element but instead of executing a particular action right away I want to display another menu, and then maybe another, ask for some input etc. My first thought was to remove the existing cmenu with screen.clear() or cleanup() but the old menu is not removed before the new one is drawn and the new menu looks like this:

```
    0. top
    1. Exit
    2. Another menu
-- end of the old menu that should go away --
    3. first
    4. second
    5. third
```

There is no remove() method for removing an item in cmenu(). I guess the fact that the old menu is not cleared is caused by 'while True' loop in display() method but when I removed it some weird stuff was going on. I am using Python 2.7, this is my current code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
# Adapted from:
# http://blog.skeltonnetworks.com/2010/03/python-curses-custom-menu/
#
# Goncalo Gomes
# http://promisc.org
#

import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)

import os
import sys
import curses
import traceback
import atexit
import time

import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")

class cmenu(object):
    datum = {}
    ordered = []
    pos = 0

    def __init__(self, options, title="python curses menu"):
        curses.initscr()
        curses.start_color()
        curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_RED, curses.COLOR_WHITE)
        curses.curs_set(0)
        self.screen = curses.initscr()
        self.screen.keypad(1)

        self.h = curses.color_pair(1)
        self.n = curses.A_NORMAL

        for item in options:
            k, v = item.items()[0]
            self.datum[k] = v
            self.ordered.append(k)

        self.title = title

        atexit.register(self.cleanup)

    def cleanup(self):
        curses.doupdate()
        curses.endwin()

    def upKey(self):
        if self.pos == (len(self.ordered) - 1):
            self.pos = 0
        else:
            self.pos += 1

    def downKey(self):
        if self.pos <= 0:
            self.pos = len(self.ordered) - 1
        else:
            self.pos -= 1

    def display(self):
        screen = self.screen

        while True:
            screen.clear()
            screen.addstr(2, 2, self.title, curses.A_STANDOUT|curses.A_BOLD)
            screen.addstr(4, 2, "Please select an interface...", curses.A_BOLD)

            ckey = None
            func = None

            while ckey != ord('\n'):
                for n in range(0, len(self.ordered)):
                    optn = self.ordered[n]

                    if n != self.pos:
                        screen.addstr(5 + n, 4, "%d. %s" % (n, optn), self.n)
                    else:
                        screen.addstr(5 + n, 4, "%d. %s" % (n, optn), self.h)
                screen.refresh()

                ckey = screen.getch()

                if ckey == 258:
                    self.upKey()

                if ckey == 259:
                    self.downKey()

            ckey = 0
            self.cleanup()
            if self.pos >= 0 and self.pos < len(self.ordered):
                self.datum[self.ordered[self.pos]]()
                self.pos = -1
            else:
                curses.flash()



def top():
    os.system("top")

def exit():
    sys.exit(1)

def submenu():
    # c.screen.clear()     # nope
    # c.cleanup()          # nope
    submenu_list = [{"first": exit}, {"second": exit}, {"third": exit}]
    submenu = cmenu(submenu_list)
    submenu.display()

try:

    list = [{ "top": top }, {"Exit": exit}, {"Another menu": submenu}]

    c = cmenu(list)

    c.display()

except SystemExit:
    pass
else:
    #log(traceback.format_exc())
    c.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I really recommend you look into using [panels](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.panel.html#module-curses.panel). Anytime you will have widgets that could possibly overlap, it makes life alot easier. This is a simple example that should get you started. (Neither curses.beep() or curses.flash() seem to work on my terminal, but that is beside the point)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import curses
from curses import panel


class Menu(object):
    def __init__(self, items, stdscreen):
        self.window = stdscreen.subwin(0, 0)
        self.window.keypad(1)
        self.panel = panel.new_panel(self.window)
        self.panel.hide()
        panel.update_panels()

        self.position = 0
        self.items = items
        self.items.append(("exit", "exit"))

    def navigate(self, n):
        self.position += n
        if self.position < 0:
            self.position = 0
        elif self.position >= len(self.items):
            self.position = len(self.items) - 1

    def display(self):
        self.panel.top()
        self.panel.show()
        self.window.clear()

        while True:
            self.window.refresh()
            curses.doupdate()
            for index, item in enumerate(self.items):
                if index == self.position:
                    mode = curses.A_REVERSE
                else:
                    mode = curses.A_NORMAL

                msg = "%d. %s" % (index, item[0])
                self.window.addstr(1 + index, 1, msg, mode)

            key = self.window.getch()

            if key in [curses.KEY_ENTER, ord("\n")]:
                if self.position == len(self.items) - 1:
                    break
                else:
                    self.items[self.position][1]()

            elif key == curses.KEY_UP:
                self.navigate(-1)

            elif key == curses.KEY_DOWN:
                self.navigate(1)

        self.window.clear()
        self.panel.hide()
        panel.update_panels()
        curses.doupdate()


class MyApp(object):
    def __init__(self, stdscreen):
        self.screen = stdscreen
        curses.curs_set(0)

        submenu_items = [("beep", curses.beep), ("flash", curses.flash)]
        submenu = Menu(submenu_items, self.screen)

        main_menu_items = [
            ("beep", curses.beep),
            ("flash", curses.flash),
            ("submenu", submenu.display),
        ]
        main_menu = Menu(main_menu_items, self.screen)
        main_menu.display()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    curses.wrapper(MyApp)
```

Some things to note when looking over your code.

Using curses.wrapper(callable) to launch your application is cleaner than doing your own try/except with cleanup.

Your class calls initscr twice which will probably generate two screens (havent tested if it returns the same screen if its setup), and then when you have multiple menus there is no proper handling of (what should be) different windows/screens. I think its clearer and better bookkeeping to pass the menu the screen to use and let the menu make a subwindow to display in as in my example.

Naming a list `'list'` isn't a great idea, because it shadows the `list()` function.

If you want to launch another terminal app like 'top', it is probably better to let python exit curses cleanly first then launch in order to prevent any futzing with terminal settings.

Comment: Thanks for the sample code (hard to find any on the web).  The line `curses.curs_set(0)` raises an exception, but all this does it set the style of the cursor, so it can be commented out, or wrapped in a try/except block

Comment: @MarkLakata good call. For reference, `curses.curs_set(0)` may or may not raise an exception depending on if the terminal supports it. There may be other hidden gotcha's in the example, so be careful.

Comment: 5 years later, still the best curses example I can find. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! - I have a question when I've updated this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61364148/562769

Comment: On windows under GitBash fails with "Segmentation fault" unless bottom one call to "panel.update_panels()" is commented out in "display()" method

Comment: 10 years later, still the best curses example I can find, and it works on python 3.10

Comment: Thanks for the very useful example, and also taking the time to give advice to the the OP