# Running system commands in Python using curses and panel, and come back to previous menu

Tags: python, subprocess, panel, curses

I'm coding a python script using several commanline tools like top, so i need a proper visual feedback. Now it is time to give it a menu, so here comes the problem.

[I found here a great approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200721/how-to-create-a-menu-and-submenus-in-python-curses) of what i need, but every try to display a feedback before come back to previous menu is futile.

I just need menus, submenus, launch commands, terminate it, and back to previous menu. a GREAT bonus would be to run them in a split of the term.

Is there any pattern/skeleton/stuff/whatever to use as template in order to display several kind of widget with a predictable output?

here is a example of code,which two examples of functions to run:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2                                                       

import curses                                                                
from curses import panel                                                     

class Menu(object):                                                          

    def __init__(self, items, stdscreen):                                    
        self.window = stdscreen.subwin(0,0)                                  
        self.window.keypad(1)                                                
        self.panel = panel.new_panel(self.window)                            
        self.panel.hide()                                                    
        panel.update_panels()                                                

        self.position = 0                                                    
        self.items = items                                                   
        self.items.append(('exit','exit'))                                   

    def navigate(self, n):                                                   
        self.position += n                                                   
        if self.position < 0:                                                
            self.position = 0                                                
        elif self.position >= len(self.items):                               
            self.position = len(self.items)-1                                

    def display(self):                                                       
        self.panel.top()                                                     
        self.panel.show()                                                    
        self.window.clear()                                                  

        while True:                                                          
            self.window.refresh()                                            
            curses.doupdate()                                                
            for index, item in enumerate(self.items):                        
                if index == self.position:                                   
                    mode = curses.A_REVERSE                                  
                else:                                                        
                    mode = curses.A_NORMAL                                   

                msg = '%d. %s' % (index, item[0])                            
                self.window.addstr(1+index, 1, msg, mode)                    

            key = self.window.getch()                                        

            if key in [curses.KEY_ENTER, ord('\n')]:                         
                if self.position == len(self.items)-1:                       
                    break                                                    
                else:                                                        
                    self.items[self.position][1]()                           

            elif key == curses.KEY_UP:                                       
                self.navigate(-1)                                            

            elif key == curses.KEY_DOWN:                                     
                self.navigate(1)                                             

        self.window.clear()                                                  
        self.panel.hide()                                                    
        panel.update_panels()                                                
        curses.doupdate()

######################################################### !# 
######################################################### !#    
############# HERE MY FUNCTIONS examples
############  Everithing works OK, but displays it awfully

def GetPid(name):
    import subprocess
    command= str(("""pgrep %s""") % name )
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
    procs = []
    salida = p.stdout
    for line in salida:
        procs.append(str.strip(line))

    return procs


def top():
    os.system("top")    

def menuGP():
    print GetPid("top")  


######################################################### !# 

class MyApp(object):                                                         

    def __init__(self, stdscreen):                                           
        self.screen = stdscreen                                              
        curses.curs_set(0)                                                   

        submenu_items = [                                                    
                ('beep', curses.beep),                                       
                ('top', top)                                      
                ]                                                            
        submenu = Menu(submenu_items, self.screen)                           

        main_menu_items = [                                                  
                ('get PID', GetPid),                                       
                ('submenu', submenu.display)                                 
                ]                                                            
        main_menu = Menu(main_menu_items, self.screen)                       
        main_menu.display()                                                  

if __name__ == '__main__':                                                       
    curses.wrapper(MyApp)
```

Thanks in advise (and sorry for my rough english)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You really have two choices. One you can leave curses mode, execute your program, then resume curses. Two, you can execute your program asynchronously, parse its output and write it to the screen.

The good news on the first option is that you don't actually need to write any fancy save_state / load_state methods for the ui. Curses does this for you. Here's a simple example to show my point

```
import curses, time, subprocess

class suspend_curses():
    """Context Manager to temporarily leave curses mode"""

    def __enter__(self):
        curses.endwin()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, tb):
        newscr = curses.initscr()
        newscr.addstr('Newscreen is %s\n' % newscr)
        newscr.refresh()
        curses.doupdate()

def main(stdscr):
    stdscr.addstr('Stdscreen is %s\n' % stdscr)
    stdscr.refresh()
    time.sleep(1)

    with suspend_curses():
        subprocess.call(['ls'])
        time.sleep(1)

    stdscr.refresh()
    time.sleep(5)

curses.wrapper(main)
```

If you run the example, you will notice that the screen created by `curses.wrapper` and the one created in `curses.initscr` when resuming are the same object. That is, the window returned by `curses.initscr` is a singleton. This lets us exit curses and resume like above without having to update each widget's `self.screen` references each time.

The second option is much more involved but also much more flexible. The following is just to represent the basic idea.

```
class procWidget():
    def __init__(self, stdscr):
        # make subwindow / panel
        self.proc = subprocess.Popen(my_args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    def update(self):
        data = self.proc.stdout.readline()
        # parse data as necessary
        # call addstr() and refresh()
```

Then somewhere in your program you will want to call `update` on all your procWidgets on a timer. This gives you the option of making your subwindow any size/place so you can have as many procWidgets as will fit. You will have to add some handling for when the process terminates and other similar events of course.

Comment: wow! impressive! Second option it's what I really need. Thanks!!