# Curses Python don't clean window when back in main menu

Tags: python, submenu, curses

[6 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200721/how-to-create-a-menu-and-submenus-in-python-curses) they proposed an excellent solution on this issue, but my changes led to an unexpected result, the window does not clear when I call the submenu function and the main menu, help me understand what is wrong.

```
import curses
from curses import panel
from test_print import get_menu_list, get_timings, time_to_seconds, GetPageChoise,\
main_menu_items, list_of_themes_end, text_discription_get

page = GetPageChoise()
class Menu(object):

    def __init__(self, items, stdscreen):
        self.window = stdscreen.subwin(5,2)
        self.window.keypad(1)
        self.panel = panel.new_panel(self.window)
        self.panel.hide()
        panel.update_panels()

        self.position = 0
        self.items = items
        self.items.append(('exit','exit'))

    def navigate(self, n):
        self.position += n
        if self.position < 0:
            self.position = 0
        elif self.position >= len(self.items):
            self.position = len(self.items)-1

    def display(self):
        self.panel.top()
        self.panel.show()
        self.window.clear()
        while True:
            self.window.refresh()
            curses.doupdate()
            for index, item in enumerate(self.items):

                if index == self.position:
                    mode = curses.A_REVERSE
                else:
                    mode = curses.A_NORMAL

                msg = '%d. %s' % (index, item[0])
                self.window.addstr(10+ index, 1, msg, mode)
            key = self.window.getch()

            if key in [curses.KEY_ENTER, ord('\n')]:
                if self.position == len(self.items)-1:
                    break
                else:
                    self.items[self.position][1]()

            elif key == curses.KEY_UP:
                self.navigate(-1)

            elif key == curses.KEY_DOWN:
                self.navigate(1)
        self.window.clear()
        self.panel.hide()
        panel.update_panels()
        curses.doupdate()


class SubMenu(object):

    def __init__(self, items, stdscreen):
        self.window = stdscreen.subwin(5,2)
        self.window.keypad(1)
        self.panel = panel.new_panel(self.window)
        self.panel.hide()
        panel.update_panels()

        self.position = 0
        self.items = items
        self.items.append(('exit','exit'))

    def navigate(self, n):
        self.position += n
        if self.position < 0:
            self.position = 0
        elif self.position >= len(self.items):
            self.position = len(self.items)-1

    def display_sub(self):
        while True:
            self.window.refresh()
            curses.doupdate()
            for index, item in enumerate(self.items):

                if index == self.position:
                    mode = curses.A_REVERSE
                else:
                    mode = curses.A_NORMAL
                next = 1
                for disript in text_discription_get():
                    self.window.addstr(next, 1, disript)
                    next +=1
                msg = '%d. %s' % (index, item[0])
                self.window.addstr(10+ index, 1, msg, mode)
            key = self.window.getch()
            if key in [curses.KEY_ENTER, ord('\n')]:
                if self.position == len(self.items)-1:
                    break
                else:
                    self.items[self.position][1]()

            elif key == curses.KEY_UP:
                self.navigate(-1)

            elif key == curses.KEY_DOWN:
                self.navigate(1)


class MyApp(object):

    def __init__(self, stdscreen):
        self.screen = stdscreen
        curses.curs_set(0)

        submenu_items = [
                ('beep', curses.beep),
                ('flash', curses.flash)
                ]
        submenu = SubMenu(sub_menu_items, self.screen) #Вывел конкретный подкаст, нужно изменить на выбор подкастов.

        main_menu_items = [
                ('beep', curses.beep),
                ('flash', curses.flash),
                ('submenu', submenu.display_sub)
                ]
        main_menu = Menu(main_menu_items, self.screen)
        main_menu.display()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    curses.wrapper(MyApp)
#Вывел меню, сделал выбор, нужно вывести Discription, сделать вызов плеера по выбору темы.
```

You can see how it looks at me at the GIF, the fact is that the proposed solution does not fit, since the submenu should display new content each time, depending on the choice.
[gif how work this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3KpN.gif)

Comment: The example isn't a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so one can only read and guess.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting a `clear()` after the function that shows the submenu worked for me:

```
class Menu(object):
    ...
    def display(self):
        ...
        if key in [curses.KEY_ENTER, ord('\n')]:
            if self.position == len(self.items)-1:
                break
            else:
                self.items[self.position][1]()
                self.window.clear() # This will clear the main menu window every time an item is selected
```

You should also clear the screen *before* showing another window because the same thing could happen if your submenu was smaller than your main menu.

Alternatively, you could clear the window at the start of every loop, as you are already redrawing the list after each key press. This way you can update the items in the menu, and will not see parts of the old menu, as you would with your current program.