# Center python curses.panel sub-menu

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-curses

I have problems in centering the following curses.panel sub-menu:

```
import curses                                                                
from curses import panel                                                     

class Menu(object):                                                          

    def __init__(self, items, stdscreen):                                    
        self.window = stdscreen.subwin(0,0)                                  
        self.window.keypad(1)                                                
        self.panel = panel.new_panel(self.window)                            
        self.panel.hide()                                                    
        panel.update_panels()                                                

        self.position = 0                                                    
        self.items = items                                                   
        self.items.append(('exit','exit'))                                   

    def navigate(self, n):                                                   
        self.position += n                                                   
        if self.position < 0:                                                
            self.position = 0                                                
        elif self.position >= len(self.items):                               
            self.position = len(self.items)-1                                

    def display(self):                                                       
        self.panel.top()                                                     
        self.panel.show()                                                    
        self.window.clear()                                                  

        while True:                                                          
            self.window.refresh()                                            
            curses.doupdate()                                                
            for index, item in enumerate(self.items):                        
                if index == self.position:                                   
                    mode = curses.A_REVERSE                                  
                else:                                                        
                    mode = curses.A_NORMAL                                   

                msg = '%d. %s' % (index, item[0])                            
                self.window.addstr(1+index, 1, msg, mode)                    

            key = self.window.getch()                                        

            if key in [curses.KEY_ENTER, ord('\n')]:                         
                if self.position == len(self.items)-1:                       
                    break                                                    
                else:                                                        
                    self.items[self.position][1]()                           

            elif key == curses.KEY_UP:                                       
                self.navigate(-1)                                            

            elif key == curses.KEY_DOWN:                                     
                self.navigate(1)                                             

        self.window.clear()                                                  
        self.panel.hide()                                                    
        panel.update_panels()                                                
        curses.doupdate()

class MyApp(object):                                                         

    def __init__(self, stdscreen):                                           
        self.screen = stdscreen                                              
        curses.curs_set(0)                                                   

        submenu_items = [                                                    
                ('beep', curses.beep),                                       
                ('flash', curses.flash)                                      
                ]                                                            
        submenu = Menu(submenu_items, self.screen)                           

        main_menu_items = [                                                  
                ('beep', curses.beep),                                       
                ('flash', curses.flash),                                     
                ('submenu', submenu.display)                                 
                ]                                                            
        main_menu = Menu(main_menu_items, self.screen)                       
        main_menu.display()                                                  

if __name__ == '__main__':                                                       
    curses.wrapper(MyApp)
```

This was copied from: 
[How to create a menu and submenus in Python curses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200721/how-to-create-a-menu-and-submenus-in-python-curses?answertab=active#tab-top)
This is the second code on that thread. I want to center the menu. self.panel.move(y,x) is not working, it is returning an error. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: File "menu3.py", line 28, in display
self.panel.move(10,10)
_curses_panel.error: move_panel() returned ERR